# C language Redirection

Tags: c, terminal, io-redirection

I have been asked to make a program named `easter.c` Now this program involves file handling. Now whenever I try to run the redirection, the terminals shows a message

> zsh: command not found: easter

Following is the screenshot. Kindly view the screenshot and help.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Comment: Your current working directory is not in `PATH`, try `./easter`.

Comment: A “command not found” error is not a redirection problem, nor is it a C problem.  In this case, it is a shell PATH setting problem, or incorrect command invocation.

Comment: Do you know that you can embed screen shots directly into the edit screen using the picture tool?

Comment: You can add the `.` directory to the `PATH` environment variable (that is a colon-separated list of directories to look for executables), but it is generally frowned upon in sysadmin circles for security reasons. That is why it is not included in `PATH` by default.

Answer (score 2):

```
./easter
```

or

```
export PATH=.:$PATH
```

Ideally, we should add the complete path of the current directory instead of `.`

Comment: Adding `.` to the beginning of the `PATH` is a security risk. If you have to add it at all (which is usually not what you want to do), it should go at the end.

Comment: Also, that only ensures that any current directory is in the path, not the specific directory, even if they move. `export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)` *could* be more useful.